# Unable to execute MongoDB query with @Query annotation in Spring

Tags: java, mongodb, spring-boot

I am facing a bit weird problem while executing the query in MongoDB using spring boot.

I have data set in the following formats.

```
{
    "_id" : "602b950000f37b023411f98f",
    "recepeName" : "testplan2",
    "orderDate" : "2021-04-20T06:32:35Z",
    "_class" : "com.company.ObjectData"
}

{
    "_id" : ObjectId("607ff6a418b64b0be4bac7fd"),
    "recepeName" : "testplan2",
    "orderDate" : "2021-04-20T06:32:35Z",
    "_class" : "com.company.ObjectData"
}
```

As you can see the difference in _id, one is **"_id" : "602b950000f37b023411f98f"** and another is **"_id" : ObjectId("607ff6a418b64b0be4bac7fd")**. To execute the query, I have written the following in interface

```
@Query("{ '_id' : { $in: [?0, ObjectId(?0)]}}")
List<MyObjectData> findObjectDataById(String id);
```

But the above query return 0 results. I also tried with the following but it did not work.

```
@Query("{'$or':[ {'_id':?0}, {'_id':ObjectId(?0)} ] }")
List<MyObjectData> findObjectDataById(String id);
```

But I am able to execute the MongoDB query in Robo3T editor with the following query

```
db.getCollection('CollName').find({"_id" : {"$in" : [ObjectId("605db41c90b901001feee9b6"), "605db41c90b901001feee9b6"]}});
```

The above query works in MongoDB editor. Please help me how to achieve the similar query in Spring MongoDB.

I include below the relevant classes.

```
public class ObjectDataEntity extends BaseEntity {

    @JsonProperty("dataId")
    @Field("dataId")
    private String projectPlanId;

    @JsonProperty("OrderRunDate")
    @Field("OrderRunDate")
    private String validationRunDate;
    
}   

@Data
public class BaseEntity {

    @JsonProperty("_id")
    @Id
    private String id = new ObjectId().toString();
}


public interface ObjectDataRepo extends MongoRepository<NVTValidationReportsEntity, String> {
       
//    @Query("{ '_id' : { $in: [?0, ObjectId(?0)]}}")
    @Query("{'$or':[ {'_id':?0}, {'_id':ObjectId('?0')} ] }")
    List<ObjectDataEntity> findObjectDataEntityById(String id);
 // ...other code   
}
```

Comment: Not sure if it helps, but mongodb has no possibility to store two objects with same `_id`

Comment: Include repository and the POJO class definitions in your post.

Comment: I have added the relevant classes for reference.